# track DML changes on all the tables in a DB of Oracle server

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a note on all the tables which have either data inserted or updated through the application.

Is there any way we can track the DML changes in the DB?

Comment: if i understand right, you want to create a log table?

Comment: @DinaBogdan yes you are correct.

Comment: See here: http://hocuspokus.net/2007/10/logaudit-tables-in-oracle/. This should help you :)

Comment: Thanks.. But is there any way to track all the tables in the DB? the above link is perfect for a single table :)

Comment: If only Oracle posted their documentation online, maybe with a section on auditing. [Wait a minute....](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000)